# How do I auto-generate an integer value for each time a user input a string value?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, increment, getter-setter

**Description**: My program asks usres to create a person's account by entering some information (i.e. name, amount..). This things are done in a while loop so that the task can be repeated again and again. The all info is stored in a file with ArrayLists. I have getter and setter methods for creating those objects.

**Problem:** I want each time a user chooses to open a new account, an account number must be created automatically. It should keep increamenting from 1. Thus the first account should have account num: 1 and second should have 2 and so on...

**Main class**:

```
//create account
BankAccount bankAcc = new BankAccount();
System.out.println("Enter Full Name:");
bankAcc.setName(sc.nextLine());
/*
System.out.println("Choose an Account Number:");//the acc Num must be generated automatically
bankAcc.setAccNum(sc.nextInt());
*/
System.out.println("Choose the initial amount:");
bankAcc.setInitiateAmount(sc.nextDouble());
//adding those into the arrayList
bankAccounts.add(bankAcc);
//writing into file
rw.writeToFile(bankAccounts);
```

**BankAccount**:

```
public BankAccount() {
        this.name = null;
        this.accNum = 0;
        this.initiateAmount = 0;
}

public void setAccNum(int accNum) {
        this.accNum = accNum;
}

public int getAccNum() {
        return accNum;
}
```

Comment: so whats the problem with having a counter variable?

Comment: I would suggest left the account number creation task for database. Auto increment account_number column by 1 for each insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple simulation (like a school assignment), you can use a `static` variable:

```
class BankAccount {
    private static int nextAccountNumber = 0;

    static int getNewAccountNumber() {
        int newNumber = nextAccountNumber;
        nextAccountNumber++;
        return newNumber;
    }

    ...

    BankAccount() {
        this.accNum = getNewAccountNumber();
    }
}
```

See [*Understanding Class Members*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: It seems very helpful answer. Still few remaining questions: (1). Do I still need keep my setAccNum method? (2). why nextAccountNumber is private static? (3). In my main class, should I call get method or set method?

Comment: *(1)* It makes sense to me that a bank account shouldn't let its account number change but it probably doesn't matter. *(2)* It's private so nobody on the outside can change it. *(3)* I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean setting the account number from outside like `bankAcc.setAccNum(BankAccount.getNewAccountNumber());` it seems redundant to me but there's no reason you can't do it that way instead of setting it automatically like I did inside the constructor. Having it done automatically is one less thing you have to keep track of in your loop.

Comment: thank u so much, I know its quite let. But the thing works. I just tried it today. thank u dear. xoxo.